# add characters of a string to an empty string

Tags: string, python-2.x

I'm trying to copy the characters entered by the user to an empty string. If the user enters `'xt'`, it will terminate. Here is what I have done:

```
z=raw_input("ent")
d=''
for j in range(len(z)):
    d+=z[j]
    if(d=="xt"):
        break
```

However, I get an error.

> IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: It should be j instead of i `d+=z[j]`

Comment: stil same srror

Comment: The code works in my machine. What input did you enter?

Comment: just a random string abc nvm it wokred a guy answered it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looping through the string itself:

```
z=raw_input("ent")
d=''
for j in z:
    d+=j
    if d=="xt":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing i in your loop, but you use j

You also are missing a colon from your if statement. Try:

```
z=raw_input("ent")
d=''
for j in range(len(z)):
    d+=z[j]
    if d=="xt":
        break
```